# Minified JS causes JS to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I'm using carabiner for CodeIgniter which can minify all the javascript files it loads.  Well, I have about 10 files that work fine, then when minified, they don't... I'm not sure exactly what doesn't work, there are no errors, just certain features that don't work. Is there any particular reason why minifying JavaScript would cause it to not work?

Comment: What error are you getting, also are you using `eval()`?

Comment: The reason: the minifying changes the code. It should preserve the functionality but apparently it doesn't. We can't say much else without your code I am afraid (aside from guessing like Nick does)

Comment: You'll also want to check to make sure you didn't miss any semicolons at the end of a statement - missing those can often cause minifying to go all wrong.  I agree with Jasper, without seeing the code it's hard to know for sure, using jslint, as S.Jones suggested is a good way to find missing semicolons and other potential problems.  Can you share the code?

Comment: Which minifier are you using?

Comment: Could we get a sample of one of these files that does not work when minified?

Answer (score 17):

You may want to try running [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) on your Javascript code before you try to minimize it.  JSLint might highlight some issues, which could allow you to minimize your code without error.

Or you may want to try another 'minification' tool.

Here are two articles I've found on 'A List Apart,' that may interest you, looking at the YUI Compressor.

"[Better JavaScript Minification](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/better-javascript-minification/)" 
"[JavaScript Minification Part II](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-minification-part-II/)"